# Two types of value in one vector C++

Tags: c++, vector

Say I have a vector for class Students, but the requirement of the question states that I cannot put grade together in the constructor, so I will have to work around it.

Is it possible that I have two values in one vector slot?

For example, the class Student and string grade are my arguments.

```
vector<Student*, string> Students;
```

So, at the end of the day, if I cout the vector, I should get Student AND the grade in one slot.

Does this work? If so, how do I push_back the value?

Otherwise, is there another way to do this?

Comment: Whether you put the grade in the constructor has little do with whether the student *contains* a grade. One would expect a Student to be able to exist before they've been graded.

Comment: _"For example, the class Student and string grade are my arguments."_ That's a `Student*`, not a `Student`. Big difference!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
std::vector<std::pair<Student*, string>> students;
```

or even better:

```
std::map<Student*, string> students;
```

**Pushing values:**

first case:

```
students.push_back(std::make_pair(x,y));
```

even better(as @snps advised):

```
students.emplace_back(x, y);
```

second case:

```
students[x]=y;
```

Be aware that in the second case you can not add multiple record with the same `Student*` value. If you try it will write over the old one.

Comment: Tip: you can construct the pair directly in-place using `students.emplace_back(x, y)`.

Comment: @Snps Yup ,emplace_back is always preferable IMO too.

Comment: Hi! I managed to do the make_pair part. The problem comes with cout. As I also had a toString() defined in the header, I have problems making the values going into the right place. Are you able to help? Thank you! :)

Comment: Put the problem with the code in different question and someone or I will help you

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways of achieving this.

A. Array of structures:

A1. Composition:

```
class GradedStudent {
    Student body;
    string grade;
    public:
    GradedStudent(const string& grade);
    // reimplement all methods of `Student`, 
    // delegating implementations to `body`
};

std::vector<GradedStudent> gradedStudents;
```

A2. Inheritance (all students have grades):

```
class Student {
public:
    Student();
};

class GradedStudent {
    string grade;
public:
    GradedStudent(const string& grade);
};

std::vector<GradedStudent*> gradedStudents;
```

A3. Inheritance + polymorphysm
    (some students have grades and some don`t):

```
class Student {
public:
    Student();
    virtual ~Student();
    virtual const string& getGrade() const { return ""; }
};

class GradedStudent : public IStudent {
    string grade;
public:
    GradedStudent(const string& grade);
    virtual string getGrade() const override { return grade; }
};

std::vector<Student*> students;
// non graded students will have empty string as a grade
```

B. Structure of Arrays approach (separate array for grades):

```
std::vector<Student*> students;
std::vector<string> grades;

for(int i = 0; i < students.size(); ++i) {
    auto* student = students[i];
    auto grade = grades[i];
}
```

C. Associative container (doesn`t honor "use std::vector" requirement):

```
std::map<Student*, string> students;

for(auto student : students) {
    auto* student = student.first;
    auto grade = student.second;
}
```

Those are classic ones. There might be more.

If all students have grades, you should really make grade a member of this class.

P.S. Do you really need to store pointers in a vector (as opposed to storing objects)?

Comment: I can store objects, but my object (using the constructor) does not contain the element grades, that's why I need to use pair.

Comment: @TimothyWongGlash I described in my answer 4 ways of achieving same thing without `pair`

Answer (score 1):

You can use std::map for this.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the help. However sadly I am only able to use Vectors. But thank you anyway!